# Check if a file is readonly in c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, readonly

I want to check if a .ini file is readonly or not in c++ for windows systems

for example:

```
if(file == readonly){
  //Do this
}
```

so far i have tried with this and it worked:

```
ofstream ofs(filename); //test to see if the file successfully opened for writing or not
```

but as a result it would delete the .ini file and it leave the file blank

PS:
1.it is not a duplicate 
2. I have searched all over internet and i found some examples that could have worked but as a result the did not compiled as they should.

Comment: You need [GetFileAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364944(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: As @MichaelWalz mentioned, use ``GetFileAttributes`` API

Comment: Why do you need to know? If you subsequently want to open the file for writing, simply don't check, and open the file using [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx). The call will fail if the file cannot be opened with the requested permissions and/or share mode. Performing a check and then opening the file can still fail, so you have to check anyway, because another process could open the file in between check and use. That's called a [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) race.

Comment: `but as a result it would delete the .ini file and it leave the file blank`  Then change the open mode to append

Comment: Whilst this is a reasonable question, you are asking it for the wrong reasons. This isn't the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're on Windows you can use:

```
DWORD attr = GetFileAttributes(filename);
if (attr != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) { 
    bool isReadOnly = attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY; 
}
```

Comment: more correct `ULONG a = GetFileAttributes(filename);
 if (a != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
 {
  bool isReadOnly = a & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY;
 }`